# error while using Datatables in asp.net MVC 5 [Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using JQuery Datatable with asp.net MVC5 but everytime I am getting the error saying "DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}`"

Below are the code details

View Details are as below

```
<p>
    <div>
        Total employees are @ViewBag.records
        <p>
            <button id="btnCall" value="Call">Call</button>
        </p>
        <table id="employeeDataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>DepartmentName</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>EmailAddress</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</p>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        { $("#employeeDataTable").dataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("DataTableUse", "DataTable")',
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype: "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                        { "data": "ID","autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "FirstName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "LastName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Designation", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "DepartmentName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Contact", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "EmailAddress", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Location", "autoWidth": true },
                ]
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

Scripts used are

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("DataTableUse");
        }

        public ActionResult DataTableUse()
        {
            ClsDataOperation objDO = new ClsDataOperation();
            List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
            lstEmployees = objDO.GetEmployeeData();
            ViewBag.records = lstEmployees.Count;
            string strJsonResultSet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstEmployees) ;
            return Json(new { data = strJsonResultSet },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Model Class Details are

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string  FirstName{ get; set; }
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }
```

Same structure is in the Database table and data as below in JSON format

```
[{"ID":1,"FirstName":"FooTest1","LastName":"Cool1","Designation":"Director","DepartmentName":"IT","Contact":"123456789","EmailAddress":"FooTest1.Cool1@test.com","Location":"NJ"},
{"ID":2,"FirstName":"FooTest2","LastName":"Cool2","Designation":"Director","DepartmentName":"IT","Contact":"123456789","EmailAddress":"FooTest2.Cool2@test.com","Location":"NJ"}]
```

DataOpeartion class has code as below

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeData()
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DevelopmentTestDatabaseContext())
                {
                    //lstEmployees = db.EmployeeData.ToList<Employee>();
                    lstEmployees = db.EmployeeData.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return lstEmployees;            
        }
```

DataContext Class as below

```
public class DevelopmentTestDatabaseContext :DbContext
    {
        public DevelopmentTestDatabaseContext() : base("name =DevelopmentTestDatabaseContext")
        {

        }
        public virtual DbSet<Employee> EmployeeData { get; set; }
    }
```

Everytime I am getting the error that says "DataTables warning: Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0' "

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Datatables expects the returned json to be in a specific format - see [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: thanks for sharing the details made the changes and sending all the parametes draw ,recordsTotal,recordsFiltered ,data

Answer (score 0):

Based off of [this link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc), I think you may need to add the dataSrc property to your ajax as an empty string. This would be because the json you are returning is not an object with a data property, but rather an array.

```
ajax: {
          url: '@Url.Action("DataTableUse", "DataTable")',
          type: "GET",
          datatype: "json",
          dataSrc: ""
      },
```

Comment: I tried this as well , if I use this it shows me "No matching records found" in the datatable. Also from the controller I am returning using                   
return Json(new { data = strJsonResultSet },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue ,in the below lines I was using string while returning in JSON so removed that

```
string strJsonResultSet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstEmployees) ;
return Json(new { data = strJsonResultSet },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of this I directly used the lstEmployees for data as below

```
return Json(new { data = lstEmployees },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

and then while returning added the following parameters as well in return statement

```
return Json(new { draw = 20, recordsTotal = lstEmployees.Count, recordsFiltered = 10, data = lstEmployees },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Thanks Mark and Grant for your help.